# How can i Create dll which can be executed only 'N' times in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I'm building a class library with bunch of methods. One of which is for creating File. I want to make it run only 'N' times and after that to throw exceptions that the limit exceeded. Is there any way to embed that 'N' in the dll or how should i store it to be secure from changing that number.
So far i've tried with static field in the class but the static field is reset everytime the application using that dll is run.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: You´d have to persists that value, e.g. in the registry or in some binary file or whatever. However this is by far too broad for a single question on SO.

Comment: Who is trying to circumvent the limit? If the answer is "the legitimate user of the same machine on which this DLL is installed", you're going to have limited success. (See e.g. the games and movie industries successes in preventing piracy in the digital age). The only truly secure way to protect your code is to keep it running *on a machine that you own and control*. Which usually then means that if there's code running on another machine you need to arrange for those machines to communicate, which is far from trivial.

Comment: I want to limit the user who will install the dll on his PC, that's the intent. But i can live with creating a web api to which they should provide a code from which i will idenitify who is the issuer and does he has exceeded his limit. 
I'm looking for the correct way which i should take to ensure maximum security or some balance (time developing / security )

Comment: You are missing Damien’s point. If the code that makes the file runs from the user’s computer, it will never be 100% safe, and much less if it’s wrtten in a decompilable language like c#. The safest way is to create the file on demand in a computer *you own* and then allowing the user to download it if he has he right to.

Comment: @InBetween has it right really - the only way you can stop someone from abusing this if they are determined to do so, is to host the whole thing online somewhere & only let them download the results.  It is trivially easy to de-compile most .Net code and then remove any protection you may have put in place.  There ARE ways around this, but these either have a cost or add complexity....  so I'd just change the whole model to remove the reliance of installing it on a local computer.  Easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest solution would be:

1. Have the local application collect all relevant local data needed to create the file.
2. Request the file to a web service that knows how to create it with the supplied data.
3. The server will verify that the user’s credentials allow him to create the file; he’s a valid registered user, has payed his dues and still has file creations to spare.
4. Create the file on the server side and allow the user to download it.

Anything running locally in your computer is susceptible to being cracked. Professional softwware and game industries have wasted millions in anti piracy devices and they’ve failed miserably, don’t expect to have any better luck.

All of this obviously has a significant cost. If the risk of your average user knowing how to circumvent a basic protection is small and the loss of profit of those few that would know how to decompile, modify and compile your application is tolerable, then who cares?

Moral of the story: stop thinking about *safest* and start thinking about *safe enough*. It’s almost always cheaper.